# Reading multiple excel files into a pandas dataframe, but also storing the file name

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

I would like to read multiple excel files and store them into a single pandas dataframe, but I would like one of the columns in the dataframe to be the file name. This is because the file name contains the date (this is monthly data) and I need that information. I can't seem to get the filename, but I'm able to get the excel files into a dataframe. Please help.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import fsspec

files = os.listdir("C://Users//6J2754897//Downloads//monthlydata")
paths = "C://Users//6J2754897//Downloads//monthlydata"

a = pd.DataFrame([2], index = None)

df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in range(len(files)):
   if files[file].endswith('.xlsx'): 
      df = df.append(pd.read_excel(paths + "//" + files[file], sheet_name = "information", skiprows=7), ignore_index=True)
      df['Month'] = str(files[file])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of operations here is incorrect. The line:

```
df['Month'] = str(files[file])
```

Is going to overwrite the entire column with the most recent value.

Instead we should only add the value to the *current* DataFrame:

```
import os

import pandas as pd

paths = "C://Users//6J2754897//Downloads//monthlydata"
files = os.listdir(paths)

df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in range(len(files)):
    if files[file].endswith('.xlsx'):
        # Read in File
        file_df = pd.read_excel(paths + "//" + files[file],
                                sheet_name="information",
                                skiprows=7)
        # Add to just this DataFrame
        file_df['Month'] = str(files[file])
        # Update `df`
        df = df.append(file_df, ignore_index=True)
```

---

Alternatively we can use [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to chain the column assignment:

```
import os

import pandas as pd

paths = "C://Users//6J2754897//Downloads//monthlydata"
files = os.listdir(paths)

df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in range(len(files)):
    if files[file].endswith('.xlsx'):
        # Read in File
        df = df.append(
            # Read in File
            pd.read_excel(paths + "//" + files[file],
                          sheet_name="information",
                          skiprows=7)
                .assign(Month=str(files[file])),  # Add to just this DataFrame
            ignore_index=True
        )
```

---

For general overall improvements we can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with a list comprehension over files. This is done to avoid growing the DataFrame (which can be extremely slow). [`Pathlib.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) can also help with the ability to select the appropriate files:

```
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd

paths = "C://Users//6J2754897//Downloads//monthlydata"

df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_excel(file,
                  sheet_name="information",
                  skiprows=7)
        .assign(Month=file.stem)  # We may also want file.name here
    for file in Path(paths).glob('*.xlsx')
])
```

Some options for the Month Column are either:

- [file.stem](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem) will give "[t]he final path component, without its suffix".

  - 'folder/folder/sample.xlsx' -> 'sample'
- [file.name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name) will give "the final path component, excluding the drive and root".

  - 'folder/folder/sample.xlsx' -> 'sample.xlsx'

Comment: Everything works great, but I wanted to know how come the ".assign" method isn't just overwriting the entire column with the most recent value like I was erroneously doing before? Is this just the nature of the assign method?

Comment: So the issue was that you had 1 DataFrame `df`. Every time that you looped you overwrote the _entire_ column with the new value. For this reason, you would only have had the most recent file in the column. Doing it in pieces (by adding the value only to the DataFrame that you've just read in) _then_ appending to `df` means you are never overwriting previous information.